# Relative Reference in conditional formatting

Tags: excel-formula

I want to highlight cell D2 Red colored if value in E2 is between 0 to 10 and if the value is 11 to 20 than yellow color and if >20 than no color. Please help somebody is this possible? and how to do this?

Comment: The solution will depend on whether you are only talking about D2 and E2 or whether you want a number of rows in column D to correspond to the same rows in column E.

Comment: entire D and E column rows

Comment: when you say "entire D and E column rows" does that include row 1 (do you have a header?)

Answer (score 0):

- select all of columns D&E (eg by clicking on column headers, with `Shift`)
- click conditional formatting -> new rule -> use formula to determine which cells to format
- in the formula box type : `=AND($E1>0,$E1<=10)`
- set fill to red, click OK

-

- select all of columns D&E (eg by clicking on column headers, with `Shift`)
- click conditional formatting -> new rule -> use formula to determine which cells to format
- in the formula box type : `=AND($E1>10,$E1<=20)`
- set fill to yellow, click OK